# Как получить текущую позицию в std алгоритме

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Нужно изнутри `std` алгоритма получить текущий индекс в коллекции или итератор текущего элемента, то можно как-нибудь сделать?
Например, в `std::generate_n` нужно знать какой элемент сейчас генерируется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скажите, как при умножении двух чисел

```
n = a * b;
```

знать, какие разряды сейчас умножаются?

Я к тому, что у вас есть строка **до** выполнения действия и строка **после**. Что вы хотите узнать? "Сейчас" - выполняется то или иное действие.

Вы можете влезть в тот же `generate_n` и добавить свой код, который будет получать эту текущую позицию (как - второй вопрос). Но пока это библиотечная функция, в код которой вы не лезете - **что** означает текущий индекс? В какой именно момент? С точки зрения вашего кода это - атомарное действие.

Comment: Да, согласен, не обдумал вопрос с этой стороны. Спасибо

Comment: Обнадежу - есть и обратная сторона :) В алгоритмах, которые используют предикаты или иные функциональные объекты, можно использовать их для *обратного вызова*, т.е. тот же генератор не только генерирует значение, но и вызывает, скажем, некоторую функцию, передавая ей номер своего вызова - фактически номер генерируемого значения (и, соответственно, элемента). Я достаточно вас запутал?

Comment: Не, я думал об этом, но просто вместо этого, я считаю будет намного проще и понятнее для того, что будет читать код написать обычный цикл

Answer (score 0):

Если используемый алгоритм гарантирует однократность вызова функционального объекта (и отсутствие копирований оного), переданного в него, то можно получить номер итерации в коде этого функционального объекта. На примере упомянутого `generate_n`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const int n = 10;
    int arr[n];
    std::generate_n(arr, n, 
        []() 
        { 
            static int i = 0; std::cout << i++ << "\n"; return i; 
        });
}
```